# Scroll Pane Activating When Frame Is Large

Tags: java, resize, jframe, scrollbars, scrollpane

I am creating a JFrame application that contains a menu, toolbar, table, and button panel. I want to use a scroll pane as the top-level container so that if the user resizes the application the buttons, etc. don't just fall off the screen.

Here is my constructor code for the main frame:

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(); // borderlayout, north=toolbar, center=table, south=buttton panel   
mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());        
mainPanel.add(new MainToolBar(inventoryActions, false), BorderLayout.NORTH);
InventoryTable inventoryTable = new InventoryTable();
JScrollPane tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(new JTable());       
mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(tableScrollPane), BorderLayout.CENTER);        
mainPanel.add(tableScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
inventoryTable.adjustColumnWidths();
mainPanel.add(new InventoryActionsButtonPanel(inventoryActions), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

JScrollPane mainScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
mainScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
mainScrollPane.setViewportView(mainPanel);

getContentPane().add(mainScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

As you can see.. I am using a JPanel to contain the toolbar, table (nested in another scroll pane), and button panels. I then put this panel inside the main scroll pane. Finally, I add the main scroll pane to the content pane.

The initial size of my application is 800x600. When I run it everything looks fine. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Initial Startup]

When I resize the frame, however, the scroll panel "activates" way before the frame gets small as you can see here:

[image: Scroll Pane Activated]

Any idea as to why my scroll panel is showing the scroll bars while the frame is still that big? Is there some preferred size that I have to set?

Thank you.

Note, if I comment out the line of code that adds the scroll pain to the main panel (center) or if I use another swing component, such as a JButton, it doesn't behave as before:

```
//mainPanel.add(tableScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Scrolls Correctly]

Comment: The JTables preferred scrollable size is part of the problem

Comment: So I should use table.setPreferredSize...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (main) problem is the fact that the `JScrollPane` is using the `JTable`'s [`getPreferredScrollableViewportSize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28%29), which overrides the `getPreferredSize` property.

By default this is set to `450x400`.

You can change this by using `JTable#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize`

Another trick is to add the `JTable` to another container (like a `JPanel`) and set this as the scroll pane's view instead

Comment: Nice thank you for the answer! Quick question, if I call setPreferredScrollableViewportSize what Dimensions should I use?

Comment: That's up to you.  Remember, this will effect the size of the scroll pane as well, so using a small size will make the initial size of the frame small if you use pack...You could overcome this by adding the `JScrollPane` to other container and override it's `getPreferredSize` to be the initial size you want...

Comment: But I don't want to hard-code any sizes in my application (except the main frame initial size which I have set to 800x600).

Comment: Then you going to have some issues.  Even if you add the table to a proxy container first, that container will use the preferred size of the table to calculate it's own preferred size...If you are using `setSize` on the window, then you could use `0x0`

Comment: Okay I think I got it. :) Thank you.